# How to remove the plus sign (+) displayed on GMap centre location?

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I'm using `GMap.NET` map control to display maps on my Windows Forms application.
I recently upgraded to `GMap.NET` build "09991dd06609".

After upgrading to the latest build, I'm getting the plus sign (+) on the centre of the map. I would like to remove that sign.

I have gone through all the `GMap.NET` control properties but I could not find any property to remove it.

When I was using the older build I was not getting the plus sign.

Comment: Perhaps this can help you: http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/discussions/210511

Comment: Thanks gleng for your response, but it's not related to plus sign removal :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some research I found the answer.
I have used the following statement to remove the plus sign(+) in GMap.NET:

```
MainGMap.ShowCenter = false;
```