# The plus sign with "debug build" keep showing up when zoom GMap.Net.Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019, gmap.net

```
gmap.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleMapProvider.Instance;
GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode = GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;
gmap.SetPositionByKeywords("Pacific Ocean");
gmap.Position = new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(48.8589507, 2.2775175);
gmap.ShowCenter = false;
```

That is my code.
[This is my picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi0go.png)

Can anyone help my with this problem?

Comment: Did you check out the code and run in Debug mode?

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608491/how-to-remove-the-plus-sign-displayed-on-gmap-centre-location